# How to merge two dataframes with preserving the same order of one of them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two **large** dataframes and I want to merge them with the same order of the first one (dataframe).

for simplisity, I will create dummy data.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': pd.Series(['A','A','A','B',"C",'C','C']), 
        'text': pd.Series(['txt2','txt1','txt3','txt1','txt2','txt3','txt1']),
        'desc': pd.Series(['text2','text1','text3','text1','text2','text3','text1'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
data = {'A': pd.Series(['txt1','txt2','txt3']), 
        'B': pd.Series(['txt1']),
        'C': pd.Series(['txt1','txt2','txt3'])}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

what I did is that I filtered on value 'A' in df and Column A on df2

```
df=df[df['name']=='A']
df2=df2[['A']]
```

and then I renamed the column in df2 form A to text, and I did the merged

```
df2.rename(columns={'A':'text'}, inplace=True)
```

```
finalDF = pd.merge(df2, df, on=['text'], how='left')
```

I want to do the same process for **Many Columns** not just A, I have a large dataframes with many columns, how can I do that in an efficient way?

please refer to below image for more understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try first [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) then [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge),

```
df2_stack = df2.stack().reset_index(level=1)

  level_1     0
0       A  txt1
0       B  txt1
0       C  txt1
1       A  txt2
1       C  txt2
2       A  txt3
2       C  txt3

# rename columns after stack
df2_stack.columns = ["name", "text"] 

  name  text
0    A  txt1
0    B  txt1
0    C  txt1
1    A  txt2
1    C  txt2
2    A  txt3
2    C  txt3

df.merge(df2_stack, on=['name','text'])
```

---

```
  name  text   desc
0    A  txt2  text2
1    A  txt1  text1
2    A  txt3  text3
3    B  txt1  text1
4    C  txt2  text2
5    C  txt3  text3
6    C  txt1  text1
```